# Can't find the debugging menu when using debugger

Tags: python, file, debugging

I am trying to use a debugger for my python file however the debugging control keys as seen in the attached photo is not appearing:
[How the debugging control keys looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw8fB.png)

Attached below is an image of what I see on my screen - the debugging control keys is not appearing as you can see when I enter the debugger:
[How my page looks like (it doesn't have the debugging control keys)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE8FZ.png)

Could anyone help and explain why?